# Continuous form only referring to the first record

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba, continuous-forms

I have a continuous form - one of the fields on the form is RecordID.

I have a label on that form, that when clicked should produce a message box with the RecordID in it via VBA:

```
MsgBox Me.RecordID
```

The label is reproduced on each row of the Continuous Form, but will only reference the first record. Even though I can see the RecordID field is different in each row of the form, I always get the same result, in this case 80029.

What's up with that?

Comment: For other's benefit: I thought I had this problem when I was trying to get information onMouseMove - but thanks to the information here I realised it was just giving me the wrong Record because the onMouseMove does not select the record the user is hovering over, and so I was always seeing data for the 'selected' record rather than the 'hovered' one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Me.RecordID` refers to the `RecordID` of the *current record*, as indicated by the black triangle in the record selector:

[image: ContinuousForm]

A `Label` control on a form cannot receive the `Focus`, so when you click on the label in another record the current record does not change and you keep getting the same `RecordID`. Note that if you put the same code into the `Click` handler for a textbox (or some other control that can receive the `Focus`) then the current record *will* change and you'll get the `RecordID` of that record.

Comment: That's got it - serves me right for trying to use a label rather than a button because it looks nicer.

Comment: You can use both in the same place but make the button transparent so the click event goes to the button but you see the label.